# Cannot get @if clause to work (checking checkbox selections) in my Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am able to use an `@if` clause in my Razor view for a radio button to display HTML:

```
@if (Model.Step.RadioButton1 == Step.Enum1.Choice1)
{
....
}
```

However, when dealing with a checkbox thusly:

```
@if (Model.Step.CheckBox1 == Step.Enum2.Choice1)
{
....
}
```

I get the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I understand the error, I just don't know how to work around it to display the HTML I have in the `{ }`.

Not sure if any other code is relvant, but will post it if it helps.  Thanks.

CODE FOR CHECKBOX:

```
 public enum Choices
    {
        [Display(Name = "Choice 1")]
        Choice1,
        ....
    }
    public class ChoicesSelectorAttribute : SelectorAttribute
    {
        public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
        {
            return Selector.GetItemsFromEnum<Choices>();
        }
    }
    [Mandatory(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one type")]
    [ChoicesSelector(BulkSelectionThreshold = 15)]
    public List<string> CheckBox1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which of these is a Generic list? Checkbox1 or Choice1? or both?

Comment: @Rob going to post the code for the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try something like:

```
@if (Model.Step.CheckBox1.Contains(Step.Enum2.Choice1))
{
....
}
```

I'm not 100% sure how the data is structured in relation to your business/view logic but I think come variation of this is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks! The correct variation was `@if (Model.Step.CheckBox1.Contains("Choice1"))`

Comment: Excellent - glad you got it sorted :-)